# Swift array doesn't hold values

Tags: arrays, swift

I ran into the following problem while trying to build something with Swift. Apparently, the values that I added into an array are not saved pass some point. They are sent just fine with the protocol while the task is running, but after it completes, if I try to see the values in the array, it returns empty.

What am i doing wrong? My guess is that it get deallocated after task finishes. If that is so, is there a way to make it strong? Is there something I should know about this task thingie? Can you please explain to me how this works and what I should do?

Here is the code:

```
var exchangeArray : ExchangeValues[] = [];

func fetchResult(){
    var currenciesOrder = ["EUR", "USD", "GBP", "CHF", "NOK", "SEK", "DKK", "CZK","TRY", "BGN", "MDL", "PLN", "XDR", "XAU", "UAH", "RUB", "RSD","CAD", "AUD", "JPY", "EGP", "BRL","HUF", "MXN","KRW", "CNY","NZD","INR","AED", "ZAR"];
    let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter();
    dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    for days in 0..2 {

        let daysToSubstract = Double(60*60*24*days);
        let date : String = dateFormat.stringFromDate(NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(-daysToSubstract));

        var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://openapi.ro/api/exchange/all.json?date=" + date);
        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession();
        var task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (response != nil){
                var err: NSError?;
                if(err?) {
                    println("request Error \(err!.localizedDescription)");
                }
                //send the result to protocol
                let results = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary;

                let temp : NSDictionary = results["rate"] as NSDictionary;

                for key in 0..currenciesOrder.count{

                    for (currencyKey : AnyObject, currencyValue : AnyObject) in temp {
                        if currenciesOrder[key] as String == currencyKey as String {
                            let tempExchange = ExchangeValues(currency: currencyKey as? String, value: currencyValue.doubleValue, date:date );
                            self.exchangeArray.append(tempExchange);
                        }

                    }

                }
                self.delegate?.didReceiveResults(self.exchangeArray);
            } else {
                println("error: \(error.localizedDescription)");
            }

        })
        task.resume();
    }

    println("\(exchangeArray.count)");
}
```

Comment: Arrays are strong. If you still have the array, you still have anything that you put in it.

You have a completion block on dataTaskWithURL and that's where you add something to exchangeArray.  Is this ever actually called?  And is the if statement ever true?  Put a breakpoint on `self.exchangeArray.append(tempExchange);` to see.

Comment: Are you saying the array doesn't hold the values because that last `println("\(exchangeArray.count)")` prints a zero?

Comment: Yes, it prints 0 the last call, and I need the array to hold the data past their sending to the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of figured out what the problem is:

 
The task block returns void, so I think it empties the array after it finishes. The result is to create another function that gets called from the task, where the array works just fine (it gets passed the values while they exist) and any further processing can be done there. 

 
 I hope this helps someone. The code is as easy as this:

```
    func sendResults(array : ExchangeValues[]) -> Void{

    println("\(exchangeArray.count)"); }
```

Of course, you can have the function return something if you need to.

Comment: if you want to ask another question please create a new thread, so not ask further questions in a designated answer.